# FBA Configuration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, forms-authentication, visual-studio-2013

I have successfully Configured FBA in Sharepoint 2013, I am facing two issues,

1. Firstly the Change Password Webpart, I am not able to get the newly generated password, the newly generated password must be saved on to a list in Sharepoint on the same site, but I am not able to get.
2. Next issue, can I change the tag name in Site Settings for FBA Membership Request Management, FBA User Management, FBA Role Management, FBA Site Configuration, if it is possible please suggest a way how to do that.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

1. When the user changes their password with the change password web part, the password is stored in the membership database (default db name is ‘aspnetdb’). Depending on the settings for the membership provider in your config file, the password will be either in plain text, encrypted or hashed (recommended). If it’s hashed you will not be able to read the password.
2. I’m not exactly sure what you mean by tag name. All of the strings for the FBA Pack that are displayed are stored in the resource files (.resx), if you would like to edit them.